# How to create a form to save into sql, sort, retrieve and export to excel

Tags: php, sql, database, excel, forms

I was just getting started with PHP, MySQL and phpmyadmin.

The reason I want to learn is to have a books database of my own.

I want to create a HTML / PHP form where I can enter the books entry (stock received). Then I want them to store in MySQL. Once I have enough books I want to export them into excel using PHP or HTML by sorting / filtering required data from the database and export them into excel.

They key thing is before all I have to save all my books titles in the database. Later by using the form I want to save the stock received into respective titles with a ability to even view and delete the stock whenever required for specific title (add stock / delete stock).

Any guidence is highly appreciated.

Regards
Narendra S

Comment: Sorry, Narendra get Tutorial from somewhere this is not allowed in SO.. Only coding helps can be done..

Answer (score 0):

This question is exceptionally broad. You have a decent idea there with PHP/MySQL and so on, but, you'll have to sit down and learn the languages and so on in order to make this happen. 
Here are some links to get you started. Read over those, get a server set up to test on, and go from there.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_mysql.htm

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Answer (score 0):

At anytime you can export your mysql data as [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) An this format can opened with Excel.